# How to prevent webserver renderening default html page(like index.htm etc) if found in a directory

Tags: ruby, webserver

I wrote a ruby program which creates a webserver on 2000 port which is used for displaying directory structure present in linux node when accessed through browser using just HTTP URL.

```
require 'webrick'
include WEBrick

s = HTTPServer.new(
:Port            => 2000,
:DocumentRoot    => "/home/abc"
)
s.start()
```

I'm accessing throgh: http://10.x.x.x:2000/dir1/dir2...

Here i'm facing problem when "index.html or index.htm or index.jsp" present in any particular directory. Webserver just rendering that page instead of showing directory/file structure present in the directory.

So how to prevent webserver rendering default html page(like index.htm etc) if foun
d in a directory instead it should show dir/file structure of that directory. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`:DirectoryIndex`](https://github.com/ruby/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/config.rb#L54) configuration for the WEBrick http server. However, the `WEBrick` project is poor documented.

You can set that option to `[]` to disable the directory index page look up.

```
require 'webrick'
include WEBrick

s = HTTPServer.new(
  :Port            => 2000,
  :DocumentRoot    => "/home/abc",
  :DirectoryIndex  => []
)
s.start()
```